# SQL Based Schedule

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scheduled-tasks

I have 3 tables.

1) The task, range and priority.

```
CREATE TABLE taskPriorities (
[taskCommand] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
[taskStartDate] [int] NOT NULL,
[taskEndDate] [int] NOT NULL,
[taskPriority] [int] NOT NULL)
```

2) Performed Tasks log

```
CREATE TABLE taskLog (
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[jobId] [int] NOT NULL,
[emailAddress] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[taskCommand] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
[executionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL)
```

3) The task notification lists

```
CREATE TABLE taskSubscribers (
[emailAddress] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[finalDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[initialDate] [datetime] NOT NULL)
```

This is the tricky part:

I need to calculate which tasks should be run each day based on the on the difference between the today and the final day. Only 1 task should be executed per day (if the calculated difference get in the middle of two (or more) tasks, the one with the most priority should be runned, then if there are more than one, the remaining task shold be the one with the bigger `taskStartDate`) and the already executed tasks should not selected. But if the `initialDate` occurs after the timeline of those tasks should be *crunched* in order to run the most tasks per task subscriber. (It's complicated to explain due English is not my native language).

It's kind of messy (at least to me), and it should be solved using SQL (T-SQL is OK). I can manage to run several consecutive querys...

So far I only have a partial success by using this query:

```
   Select audience.jobId,
      audience.emailAddress, 
      audience.taskCommand, 
      audience.execDate, 
      audience.remainingDays, 
      audience.taskStartDate, 
      audience.taskEndDate, 
      audience.taskPriority
 From (Select 1 As jobId, /*Hardcoded*/
              remainings.emailAddress, 
              tp.taskCommand, 
              GetDate() As execDate, 
              remainings.remainingDays, 
              tp.taskStartDate, 
              tp.taskEndDate, 
              tp.taskPriority
         From taskPriorities tp 
              Inner Join (Select subs.emailAddress, 
                                 DATEDIFF(DAY, GetDate(), subs.finalDate) As remainingDays 
                            From taskSubscribers subs) remainings On remainings.remainingDays Between tp.taskEndDate And tp.taskStartDate) audience
      Left Join taskLog tl On tl.taskCommand = audience.taskCommand And tl.emailAddress = audience.emailAddress
Where tl.id Is Null
     And audience.taskCommand = (  Select Top 1 tpr.taskCommand
                                     From taskPriorities tpr
                                    Where audience.remainingDays Between tpr.taskEndDate And tpr.taskStartDate
                                 Order By tpr.taskPriority desc , tpr.taskStartDate, tpr.taskEndDate)
```

(All this in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67dd7/1/0)

Some examples:

```
          |----------|---------|
          -20        -10       0
Task 1 P1   |-----------|

Task 2 P2        |-----------|
```

Subscriber 1, with initial date <= -20 on day -17 should run task 1. On day -15 should run task 2 (task 1 was already executed).

Subscriber 2, with Initial date -15, should run task 1 because it is the older task and on day -14 should run task 2.

Can anyone give me some leads on the *crunching* part?

Thanks

Comment: Its even more complicated to understand the requirement :)

Comment: I  think I have almost understood your question. Could you explain this part:-->> **But if the initialDate occurs after the timeline of those tasks should be crunched in order to run the most tasks per task subscriber.**

Comment: So, to sum it up, you are trying to build a task automation where the task which has **not been** run the longest will be run today(Assuming finalDate to be the date it has been run the last).--(continued)

Comment: If the difference for two tasks is the same, you want to take the one which has more priority. If they are still the same, you want to take the one which has a larger value of `taskStartDate`. (continued)

Comment: I still don't understand the `initialDate` column. That difference you are talking about, -15 and -20, are they the difference of `getdate()` and `initialDate` column?

Comment: And what are you doing here-->>> `remainings.remainingDays Between tp.taskEndDate And tp.taskStartDate`? How can an `int` be compared against a date?

Comment: taskStartDate and taskEndDate are both int...

Comment: Dates can be stored as int in database. E.g. 0212204 is today's date. What I was asking is why are comparing the difference(which is purely numeric) to these fields?

Comment: `Select subs.emailAddress, DATEDIFF(DAY, GetDate(), subs.finalDate) As remainingDays From taskSubscribers subs` calculates the days between now and the `finalDate` of each subscriber... The SQLFiddle  link might be helpful to understand the whole query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65992/discussion-between-sourav-agasti-and-hiperix).